# javascript string replace multiple special characters

Tags: javascript, string

I know how to replace single character in string, but what if i want to replace multiple characters?

```
var replaceMe = "Přemysl Oráč Šestý";


$("body").append( replaceMe );
```

For example:

- ě = e;
- č = c;
- ď = d;
- ř = r;

and so on. In my case *Přemysl Oráč Šestý* should be *Premysl Orac Sesty*

How to do that if I have multiple characters?

Here is my codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RaXvjo?editors=0010

Comment: Use regular expression with OR condition. Can be done easily..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18391901/5812121

Answer (score 1):

Just call `.replace()` method multiple times:

```
var replaceMe = "Přemysl Oráč Šestý";

var replaced = replaceMe
  .replace(/ě/g, "e")
  .replace(/č/g, "c")
  .replace(/ď/g, "d")
  .replace(/ř/g, "r")

$("body").append(replaced);
```